# How can i make my code generate similar but still different results wihtout needing to type it all out?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote code which makes a square with a random number between 1 and 16.  I want to make a grid of squares with a random number.  I know how to do it by repeating parts of the code multiple times and changing some numbers, but I know this will be boring to do and won't turn out great. Is there a way to make a short code that will do the repeat work for me?

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.title("root")
root.geometry("500x300")

F1 = Frame(root, height=150, width=250, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
F1.place(x=0, y=0)

L1 = Label(root, font=("bold", 10))
L1.place(x=125, y=75)
R1 = randint(1, 16)

if R1 == 1:
    L1.config(text="1")

if R1 == 2:
    L1.config(text="2")

if R1 == 3:
    L1.config(text="3")

if R1 == 4:
    L1.config(text="4")

if R1 == 5:
    L1.config(text="5")

if R1 == 6:
    L1.config(text="6")

if R1 == 7:
    L1.config(text="7")

if R1 == 8:
    L1.config(text="8")

if R1 == 9:
    L1.config(text="9")

if R1 == 10:
    L1.config(text="10")

if R1 == 11:
    L1.config(text="12")

if R1 == 13:
    L1.config(text="13")

if R1 == 14:
    L1.config(text="14")

if R1 == 15:
    L1.config(text="15")

if R1 == 16:
    L1.config(text="16")
```

Comment: IndentationError - lots of. Please fix.

Comment: make a function.. or make a dictionary ..

Answer (score 3):

you can convert R1 to `str` and instead of many `if` statements you can do this:

```
L1.config(text=str(R1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution would be

```
<...>
R1 = randint(1, 16)

if R1 <= 7:
    L1.config(text=str(R1))
```

If the relationship between your variable `R1` and the text you want to display is more complicated, you could use a dictionary.
Just a random example to give you a rough idea:

```
R1 = randint(1, 16)

r1_texts = {
    1: 'This one is special',
    2: 'This one is special, too',
    3: 'This one is extremely special'
}
for i in range(4, 17):
    r1_texts[i] = 'The random number is {}'.format(i)

L1.config(text=r1_texts[R1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
R1 = randint(1,16)
L1.config(text=str(R1))
```

Comment: Same answer is taken 6 minutes before you posted. Please avoid duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context, but you can implement a function like this:

```
def text_configuration(L1, R1):
    if R1 in range(1,16):
        L1.config(text=str(R1))
    else:
        raise Exemption
```

Or taking the random assignment into account, and provided you don't need it in a different context:

```
def random_text_configuration(L1):
    R1=randint(1,16)
    L1.config(text=str(R1))
```

Comment: Looping on values from 0 to 15 until you get to the value you already know is useless. Your last piece of code is the copy of a previous answer.

Comment: you're right, I removed the first answer, I had opened the editor before the other answer arrived...